# Showing that $x^2+y^2$ is irreducible in $k[x,y]$ provided that $\sqrt{-1}\notin k$

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Let $k$ be any field. I know how to prove "by hand" the fact that $x^2+y^2$ is irreducible in $k[x,y]$ assuming that the polynomial $x^2+1$ has no roots over $k$. For that, one has to impose the equation
$$
x^2+y^2=(ax+by)\cdot(a'x+b'y),
$$
expand the RHS and then, after solving the system of equations for $a,a',b,b'$, one finds that $a'a=1$ and $a^2+b^2=0$, so that $0=(a')^2(a^2+b^2)=1+(a'b)^2$, and arrives a contradiction.

But is there a better way of doing it? By "better" I mean a faster/more elegant/more technological way. For example, I don't see how Eisenstein criterion could be used here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally true that the homogenization of an irreducible polynomial is irreducible, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/512395/homogenization-of-an-irreducible-polynomial-is-irreducible) for example. As $x^2+y^2$ is the homogenization of $x^2+1$, we can conclude.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if the image of your polynomial $x^2+y^2$ after quotienting the base ring $k[y]$ by a proper ideal is irreducible, then $x^2+y^2$ was irreducible. So quotient by $(y^2-1)$; the image of your polynomial in this case is $x^2+1$ which you have supposed to be irreducible. So the original polynomial was irreducible.

Comment: You need the ideal that you're quotienting out to be prime.

Comment: @LukasHeger If the base ring is a domain, I thought it need only be proper? Let $R$ be the ring, $f\in R$ monic. Since $f$ is monic, its image $\pi(f)$ is nonzero in $(R/I)[x]$. (Here we used $I \neq R$.) Now suppose $f$ is reducible; reduce it $f=gh$. The leading coeffs of $g,h$ must be units. So $\pi$ does NOT kill them ($I \neq R$). In particular, $\pi(g), \pi(h)$ have the same degrees as $g,h$, resp. And $g,h$ were non-constant. We conclude $\pi(g),\pi(h)$ are non-constant, therefore non-units. So $\pi(f)$ is reducible. So $f$ reducible $\implies$ $\pi(f)$ reducible.

Comment: How do you conclude that a non-constant polynomial is a non-unit? After all, $2x+1$ is a unit in $\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z[x]$

Comment: @LukasHeger If $R$ is a domain, the units of $R[x]$ are exactly the units of $R$. In your example, the base ring $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ is not a domain. A reference: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Units_of_Ring_of_Polynomial_Forms_over_Integral_Domain

Comment: Yes, but why is $R/I$ a domain? It need not be.

Answer (score 0):

If it were reducible, then so it is in $k(y)[x]$. Since $y$ is a unit, so would $(x/y)^2 + 1$. Replace $k(y)[x]$ by $k(y)[xy^{-1}]$, then equivalently $x^2 + 1$ is reducible in $k(y)[x]$. Then $\sqrt{-1}$ exists in $k(y)$.  Let $p,q \in k[y]$ coprime and $q$ monic  such that $p(y)^2/q(y)^2 = -1$, or $p(y)^2 + q(y)^2 = 0$. Looking at the leading coefficient yields a root of $X^2 + 1$ over $k$, contradction.

Comment: Would downvoters care to explain?